# 2 stroboscopes: 1 constant, 1 decelerating at decelerating rate. Is it predictable when they both would 'meet'?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

2 stroboscopes a and b.

Frequencys are:
$$
F[a] = 1/sec
$$

$$
F[b] = \frac{\sqrt{T² - C²}}{T}/sec
$$

Where C is a constant and T is time ≥ C

---

##### Would there excist a method of predicting at what T ≥ C both lights turn on simultaneous, without bruteforcing over T?

---

Example with C = sqrt{39} and Time 8 would yield:
$$
\sqrt{8² - 39} = 5.
$$
Because 5 is integer and A flashes at 1/sec., A and B are simultaneous activated at this point.

---

Another example with T = 7
$$
\sqrt{7² - 39} = 3.16.
$$
Here B will not be simultaneous with A.

I hope the notation makes sense.

Comment: "This means at T == sqrt{C}, F = ∞"
can you explain this step?

Comment: Thanx for pointing out. It was a mistake. Modified.